# Derivation of the weak form for a parabolic PDE - initial-boundary problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, brownian-motion, calculus-of-variations, parabolic-pde

I am reading a paper that seems to provide a solution for the problem I am facing but being unfamiliar with  variational calculus I get lost in notation.

I am trying to derive the weak form from the strong form in the following problem.

Solving for $u(t,x)$ for $ (t,x) \in [0,T] \times R^d $.
The set $A \in R^d$ is open with boundary $\partial A$.

The strong form is as follows:
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,x) - \frac{1}{2} \sum_i \sum_j a_{ij}(x) \frac{\partial^2 u(t,x)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} - \sum_i b_i(x) \frac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial x_i} = 0\;,\; on \; (t,x) \in [0,T] \times A, $$
$$ u(0,x) = 1, \; x \in A, $$
$$ u(t,x) = 0, \; x \in \partial A,\; t > 0$$

The paper indicates that the weak form is as follows:
$$ \frac{d u}{d t}(u(t,.),v) + g(u(t,.),v) = 0, \forall v \in H_0^1(A), $$
$$ u(0,.) = 1, $$
where $ g(u(t,.),v) = \frac{1}{2}  (a \nabla u(t,.), \nabla v) - \left( (b-\text{div } a)\nabla u,v\right) $.

I assume $ (a,b) = \int_A a(x) b(x) dx  $.

This seems to be a classical result, the issue is that I am not familiar with the notation, nor with tensor/variational calculus. I assume that it involves a multivariate integration by part, which is foreign to me.

- how to derive  $g(u(t,.),v)$ ?
- what is the divergence of the matrix-valued $a$ ?

I get the part with $b$: $\int_A \left( \sum_i b_i(x) \frac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial x_i} \right) v(x) dx  = (b\nabla u,v)$.
The problem is the part with $a$.

Thanks a lot for any help !

Source of the problem:

> P. Patie, C. Winter, (2008) "First exit time probability for multidimensional diffusions: A PDE-based approach"

Comment: The answer is really just integration by parts. This should also clarify what is meant by $\operatorname{div}$ in this case (you may want to use the product rule on that term).

Comment: Ok, I will try to look more into this. The wikipedia part on IBP in higher dimensions was intimidating. I should find a more "textbook" style explanation.

Comment: You have to be a little careful with regularity issues, but to get a rough understanding, just assume that you can extend $u(t,\cdot)$ by $0$ to the entire space. Then you can just integrate every component separately and the boundary terms vanish so that you end up with $\int (\partial_i u)v=-\int u\partial_i v$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I posted what I found as an answer based on your advice. The issue is that I don't find the same result as the paper (T_T). Also I am not sure what happens with weird boundaries such as $x \in (0,\infty)$. Does $v(x)$ vanish at infinity too ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is correct, there is still some uncertainty for some parts.

Focusing on:
$$ \sum_i \sum_j \int a_{ij}(x) \partial_{ij} u(x) v(x) dx \tag{1} \label{1}$$

For a given dimension (e.g. $x_j$) we do an IBP.
We have $[a_{ij}(x) \partial_{i} u(x) v(x)]_{\partial A}=0$, since $v(x) = 0$ at the boundary.
$$ \int a_{ij}(x) \partial_{ij} u(x) v(x) dx = [a_{ij}(x) \partial_{i} u(x) v(x)]_{\partial A} - \int ( \partial_j a_{ij}(x)v(x)+ a_{ij}(x)\partial_j v(x))\partial_i u(x)dx \\
= - \int \partial_j a_{ij}(x)v(x) \partial_i u(x) dx - \int a_{ij}(x)\partial_j v(x)\partial_i u(x)dx
$$

Now we sum the two terms over $i$ and $j$.
For the first term we have:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_i \sum_j \int \partial_j a_{ij}(x)v(x) \partial_i u(x) dx  & 
= \int \left( \sum_i \left(  \sum_j \partial_j a_{ij}(x)\right) \partial_i u(x)\right)  v(x) dx \\
& = \int \left( \sum_i (\text{div } a)_i   \partial_i u(x)\right)  v(x) dx \\
& = (\text{div } a \nabla u,v)
\end{align} 
$$
where $ (\text{div } a)_i = \left( \sum_j \partial_j a_{ij}(x) \right)_i $.

For the second term we have:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_i \sum_j  \int a_{ij}(x)\partial_j v(x)\partial_i u(x)dx 
& = \int \sum_j \left( \sum_i a_{ij}(x)  \partial_i u(x) )  \right) \partial_j v(x) dx \\
& = ( a\nabla u , \nabla v)
\end{align} 
$$

Plugging this in $(\ref{1})$, we get:
$$ (1) = - (\text{div } a \nabla u,v) - ( a\nabla u , \nabla v). \tag{2} $$

Coming back to the original term, we wanted:
$$ - \int \left( \frac{1}{2} \sum_i \sum_j a_{ij}(x) \partial_{ij} u(x) + \sum_i b_i(x) \partial_i u(x) \right) v(x) dx. \tag{3} $$
Using the fact that $ \int \sum_i  b_i(x) \partial_i u(x) v(x) dx = (b\nabla u,v),\; $ and (2), we get:
$$ \begin{align}
(3) & = \frac{1}{2} (\text{div } a \nabla u,v) + \frac{1}{2} ( a\nabla u , \nabla v) - (b\nabla u,v) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} ( a\nabla u , \nabla v) - ( (b -  \frac{1}{2} \text{div } a  ) \nabla u, v )
\end{align}
$$

This is different from what the paper gives, I have an additional "$\frac{1}{2}$" (who made an error ?):
$$ \begin{align}
(g) & = \frac{1}{2} ( a\nabla u , \nabla v) - ( (b -  \text{div } a  ) \nabla u, v )
\end{align}
$$

So I see that it **mostly** works if we have a nice bounded set such as $A=\{l_i<x_i<u_i\;;i=1,...,d\}$.
But I am not sure what happens if it is unbounded on one side: $A=\{x_i<u_i\;;i=1,...,d\}$.
Or worse, it is a weird boundary: $A=\{x_i-x_j<u_i\;;i,j=1,...,d\}$.
Feel free to comment, I will edit the answer accordingly.